# How to fetch table data from AWS DynamoDB using python, optimally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to fetch table data from Amazon DynamoDB and am currently using **boto3** library for the same. Currently, I'm using `scan()` method.

But, I see that `scan()` is the *most time-consuming* and *most expensive* way to access data in DynamoDB as the search is sequential. Scans are also slow especially with large tables and most likely we will consume all the provisioned throughput within no time, so for that reason, I have 2 queries regarding the same:

- How do we fetch all the table data and store it in a pandas dataframe?
- How to fetch only the TOP TEN records from a table?

Thanks

Comment: If you want all data you need scan - you should not do that but if you need it go ahead. Not efficient and not cost-effective because you are using the wrong database tech if you need to perform that query often. What are top ten records? According to what criteria? You can provision a sort key and then query based on that sort key, granted that all request items have to have the same hash key.

Comment: One way to fetch top 10: add a GSI with constant partition key, variable attribute as sort key, then query against the GSI for the constant partition key with Limit 10 and ScanIndexForward false. Not recommended for very large datasets because the GSI is all stored on one partition.

Comment: @luk2302, so to fetch all the records, is `scan()` the only way? And the 2nd requirement is basically to fetch any 10 rows/records from a table from AWS DynamoDB.

Comment: @jarmod, the requirement is to fetch any 10 records, just to get an idea about what data is being stored in a particular table ... can you suggest accordingly please, thanks.

Comment: Well, any 10 records is not typically described as "top 10", hence my earlier advice on GSI. If you simply want 10 records, then invoke scan with Limit 10. And, yes, scan is the operation that will give you all records (actually termed "items" in DynamoDB). Be aware that the results may be paginated.

Comment: @jarmod, gotcha, thanks soo much for your suggestion. Have a good day. :)